# List items in array of objects

Tags: javascript

If I have an array like this:

```
var arrayData = [
    {"id" : 1, "title" : "a title", "info" : "blah blah"},
    {"id" : 2, "title" : "another title", "info" : "lalala"},
    ...
];
```

How would I loop through the array and find the value of `title`?

```
for (var i=0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    // console.log('title of this post is:')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i=0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    console.log(entries[i].title);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use ES5, you can get an array of titles like this:

```
arrayData.map( function(record) { return record.title; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Each object in the array can be accessed by its index e.g. `arrayData[0]`, and the properties of that object can be accessed in the regular fashion e.g `arrayData[0].title`, so your loop just needs to use the arrayName and i:

```
var arrayData = [
    {"id" : 1, "title" : "a title", "info" : "blah blah"},
    {"id" : 2, "title" : "another title", "info" : "lalala"}
];

for (var i=0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
    console.log('title of this post is: ' + arrayData[i].title)
}
```

Output:

> ```
> title of this post is: a title
> title of this post is: another title
> ```